# Llena combobox anidados desde BBDD

Tags: java, java-swing, combobox

Tengo 2 tablas relacionadas (Directores y Películas) y estoy trabajando en un crud donde tengo una ventana para modificar/actualizar registros de películas (titulo, país ,etc...) que traigo de la BDD, las películas las muestro con un combobox y la idea es que al seleccionar las distintas peliculas me cargue en los jtextfield cada registro, mi problema es que no logro mostrar el director relacionado en otro combobox, otro problema que se presenta es que puede que haya películas que no tengan director asignado...como seria la mejor forma de resolver esto ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    comboPelicula = new JComboBox();
    comboPelicula.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            
            String pelicula= comboPelicula.getSelectedItem().toString();  //
            String cod_peli= Main.gbb.dameCodigo(pelicula, "-");       //DEVUELVE CODIGO
            Pelicula miPelicula = null;                              //INSTANCIA PARA LLENAR CAMPOS
            try {
                miPelicula = Main.gbb.damePeli(Integer.parseInt(cod_peli)); //              
                
                
                txtTitulo.setText(miPelicula.getTitulo());
                miPelicula.getDirector(); //--------> ME DEVUELVE EL CODIGO DEL DIRECTOR, NO ME SIRVE PARA EL INDEX DEL COMBOBOX...

                txtPais.setText(miPelicula.getPais());
                txtDuracion.setText(miPelicula.getDuracion());
                txtGenero.setText(miPelicula.getGenero());
```

Comment: Si tu función getDirector te retorna el nombre del director y el texto coincide con los textos que tendrás en el combobox de directores, ahí mismo tendrás que buscar y seleccionar el ítem del combobox que tenga ese texto y si no retorna director, seleccionas un ítem que ya tienes localizado, el primero por ejemplo,que muestre algo como No Definido.

Comment: getDirector me devuelve un int, que es el primary key de la tabla director, por eso no puedo comparar Strings

Comment: Pues si no puedes relacionar lo que te retorna getDirector con los textos de la combobox,lo que quieres hacer es imposible. Así que no te queda otra que relacionar ese entero con los ítems de la combobox de alguna manera